# useEffect or useMemoized in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, react-hooks, hook-widgets

If I want to initialize object in hook widget, should I use `useEffect` or `useMemoized`?

```
class CreateUserScreen extends HookWidget {
  late ABC abc;
  CreateUserScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    useEffect(() {
      abc = ABC();
      return null;
    });
     ...
}
```

or

```
class CreateUserScreen extends HookWidget {
    
      CreateUserScreen({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
       final abc = useMemoized(() => ABC());
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Depending what the object do or if you want a different instance each time, if not check out useRef, it creates an object once per widget life cycle

Answer (score 1):

you should use useEffect and useState for HookWidget is best as per my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

useEffect -> when you want an effect (callback, listening other objects, more reactive stuff)

useMemoized -> expensive calculations that don't change that much (color based on a bool input and some other data, math, generate list based on other values)

useRef -> Creates an instance of an object as a reference and holds it until the widget is disposed (for example a http instance, you only want one for other things in your widget)

Comment: useEffect is also good when you need to specify a dispose action.

Comment: a dispose action is commonly a callback, but yeah, everything that needs to be orchestrated as a series of effects to other objects or controllers